# PhP Mail script - Error generate 'FOR loop script' in the $message variable

Tags: php, email

How do i add the php for loop script to generate the content on the email (pick up from Database) as highlighted below?

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Your's Weekly Newsletter </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi $to,</p>
<p>Here are the highlight of the deals this week:</p> 
<br />

<p>    **<?php
   for ($i=0;$i<=$totalCount;$i++) {
   echo \"Deal Description = $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array2[$i] <br />\";
   echo \"Deal URL = <a href=\"$HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array3[$i]\"> More >> $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array1[$i] </a> <br />\";
   echo \"Days Left = $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array4[$i] <br />\";

   echo \" <hr width=\"auto\" style=\"border: 1px dotted #000000\" size=\"1\"> \";
   }
?>**
</p>

<p> <u>Forward this email</u> to your friends/family and let them know you like this. </p>
<br />
</body>
</html>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed php code inside a php string's content. You have to split it up like this:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Your's Weekly Newsletter </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi $to,</p>
<p>Here are the highlight of the deals this week:</p> 
<br />

<p>    **";
for ($i=0;$i<=$totalCount;$i++) {
    $message .= "Deal Description = " . $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array2[$i] . "<br />";
    $message .= "Deal URL = <a href=\"" . $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array3[$i] . "\"> More >> " . $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array1[$i] . "</a> <br />";
    $message .= "Days Left = " . $HighlightWeeklyNewsletter_array4[$i] . "<br />";
    $message .= "<hr width=\"auto\" style=\"border: 1px dotted #000000\" size=\"1\">";
}

$message .= "**
</p>

<p> <u>Forward this email</u> to your friends/family and let them know you like this. </p>
<br />
</body>
</html>
";
```